# Installing Android on Linux set-top box

Tags: installation, linux

Ok.. here is where I stand. I have a STB that has an old version(12.4) of Ubuntu on it. I was told that it previously had Android 5 on it but it was overwritten when Linux was installed. What I would like to do is wipe the device and re-install Android. The problem is I'm not sure where to start. I've done a fair bit of Googling but have not found anything on how to do a fresh install of Android. Is there an image somewhere that I can put on a SD card? Could someone point me in the right direction here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you mention the link for this STB? Their are devices that requires only dedicated tools for flashing sometimes, or the flashing method differs from the common ones.